# Magento showing error when loging in backend using chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, magento, magento-1.7

I just freshly installed Magento-1.7.0.2 on my LAMP server. The path was something like this `www/MyProjects/MyStore`. I made every step by step installation. At last I got two option to go store fronted and store back-end. When I clicked on store fronted it just redirected me to the home page and when I clicked on the store back-end it asked me for the username and password. But when I gave all the username and password still it not logged in.At that time I was using chrome browser. But when I just opened that link in my firefox browser it just opened the back-end smoothly. So can someone tell me what is the problem here to open that link in chrome browser? Any help and suggestions will be appreciable. Thanks

**UPDATE**

When I am going to login with my username and password it is showing something like `Invalid User Name or Password.`. But this one is working fine in firefox.

Comment: In chrome, did you get any error or what error did you get in the error console?

Comment: When I am going to login with my username and password it is just showing `Invalid User Name or Password.` but in firefox it is running okay

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file first then make comment out on this section (it's lines 85 to 102). \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php

```
/*
// session cookie params
    $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
  */
```